# Game Vs. Play en el contexto de la gamificación

Tags: traducción, extranjerismos

Estoy realizando un curso de gamificación en inglés, y hay un concepto que quisiera poder traducir al español pero no encuentro aún cómo, ¿alguien podría ayudarme a tener una aproximación en español?

El concepto tiene que ver con la diferencia entre *Play* y *Game*:

=============

**Play** en el contexto de jugar con cierta libertad bajo ciertos límites:
[image]

=============

**Game** como una serie de elecciones significativas:
[image]

Comment: Sospecho que no hay manera de traducir eso de manera transparente, sino que el traductor tiene que pasar al frente y hablar con voz propia explicando que el español usa una misma palabra para donde el inglés usa dos. Pero voy a pensarlo más.

Comment: *Ludificación* suena mucho mejor en castellano.

Comment: Creo que esto es off-topic.. ya que esto es linguistica del ingles y no del español...
Asi que terminaria siendo una pregunta de como explicar a alguien de habla hispana como diferenciar "play" de "game"

Comment: El traductor puede agregar algunas palabras, por ejemplo "jugar libremente sin rumbo fijo" o "juego libre, como se juega en la infancia".  Ahora un ejemplo concreto.  Si la frase dice "When we create a game, we should not forget that we are there to play," podemos traducir "game" con *juego* , y "we are there to play" con *venimos al juego para divertirnos*.  Para expresar la idea, hay que pensar en la idea que se esta expresando, en su concepto puro, y luego expresar la idea lo mas claro posible en el idioma de los que nos van a oir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque ambas palabras en inglés se puede traducir como *juego*, según el contexto hay muchas posibilidades (excluyo traducciones no lúdicas como *obra de teatro*):

**Game**

- *juego*
  el conjunto de reglas
- *partido*
  cada iteración de un juego (de deportes)
- *partida*
  cada iteración de un juego (de mesa o de vídeo)

**Play**

- *jugada*
  un determinado movimiento o secuencia de movimientos dentro de un partido o partida.
- *jugueteo / recreo*
  el acto de jugar libremente sin conjunto de reglas

En los ejemplos que das, yo probablemente diferenciaría los términos con **juego** y **recreo** — *recreo* nos recuerda a todos de la infancia cuando nos divertíamos de forma abierta y libre, sin la rigidez de los deportes.

Answer (score 0):

"Game" se traduce usualmente como "juego", y me parece apropiado en la mayoría de las situaciones, especialemnte si es precedido por articulo determinado "el".

"Play", en cambio, como verbo se traduce en "jugar", y como sustantivo puede cambiar segun el contexto: "jugada" por ejemplo "La jugada que hizo Leonel Messi fue sorprendente", "jugueteo" como en "el jugueteo de los niños era ruidoso". A veces "juego" se utiliza sin especificar que hay una estructura rigida y movimientos conscientes como en "el juego de las olas era tranquilizante" pero usualmente es lenguaje figurativo.

Answer (score 0):

Para mi la diferencia radica en que el uso de que "play" es una ramificación de significados:

El significado de "Play" esta mas acercado a "ejecución y movimiento", ya que su raíz etimológica viene de "moverse rápidamente".

Es esta manera en la que "Play" puede referirse casi a cualquier actividad estructurada que se refiera a mover o iniciar algo:

Revisemos los siguientes ejemplos:

> Play the song
>   Play the movie
>   Play the piano

los tres tienen un significado similar que denota la acción de iniciar y hacer algo:

> Canta la canción
>   Reproduce la pelicula
>   Toca el piano

De esta misma manera "Play" como sustantivo puede significar otras cosas cuyo efecto sea la ejecución de un movimento:

> That play was a smart play / Esa fue una jugada inteligente (deportes)
>   The play starts in 5 minutes / La obra (teatral) inicia en 5 minutos

Y finalmente esta la acepción de "jugar", que se puede entender que pudo haber adquirido ese significado de cómo los juegos movidos al existir mucho movimiento tendrías un "play"

Y por otro lado.... 
**Game**

Que es simplemente un "juego", un juego con un sistema de reglas estructuradas
ya sea dentro de los deportes o distintos ámbitos.

Comment: Mike, si crees que es *off topic* entonces por qu'e escribes una respuesta?  Por otra parte, no hace falta traducir todas las acepciones y todos los usos, si OP nos dio los dos usos que le interesan.  Por ejemplo *Play the song* no hace falta.